# MSG.EXE User on Domain (User disconnected or doesn't exist)

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, domain

So I am trying to use msg.exe on the command prompt on a domain named **district**. I can successfully call the method `msg myUsername test message` and receive a message to myself but whenever I do `msg friendUsername test message`, I get the error `friendUsername does not exist or is disconnected`. I know that this user is logged in because they are right next to me trying to get this to work.

Whenever I do `net user` it only lists the Guest and Administrator account and not my own as it is stored somewhere on the network. Each user has their own personal drive which is stored on the **district** domain. (Net send does not work by the way). I found out that I *probably* need to use the `/server:` part of the command but I am not sure what server my user is on. If I don't specify a server, it goes to default but it cannot find the other users? I tried checking `/server:district` but it won't even send a message to myself anymore.

Also, I don't know if it matters or not, but I can find users and computers successfully on the Active Directory.

How can I successfully send a message?

Answer (score 1):

#### How can I successfully send a message?

Using [`msg`](http://ss64.com/nt/msg.html):

```
msg friendUsername /server:servername message
```

Using [`net send`](http://ss64.com/nt/net_send.html):

```
net send friendUsername message
```

- To use `net send` the `Messenger` service must be running, many organisations choose not to run this service.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [msg](http://ss64.com/nt/msg.html) - Send a pop-up message to a user.
- [net](http://ss64.com/nt/net.html)  - The NET Command is used to manage network resources.
- [net send](http://ss64.com/nt/net_send.html) - The NET Command is used to send network messages

Comment: Net send doesn't work anymore as the command `send` isn't a command supported anymore. I understand how to use the message command. What I'm confused about is how to find which server my user is in.